# What are the minimum stats I need for a Call of Cthulhu combat?

Tags: call-of-cthulhu

When I run Trail of Cthulhu and I need to prepare for a combat quickly, I scribble down something like the following:

*Gangster: Athletics 10, Health 10*

Those are the minimum statistics I need to run the combat.

What is the equivalent in Call of Cthulhu? If I needed to scribble down some stats for an opponent, what would I write?

(If it matters, I'm using 5th edition, but I'm interested in answers for other editions, since they're all similar.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Dude: Random Weapon Type Skill x%, Dmg ydy+y; HP zz*

For example,

*Gangster: Guns 65%, Dmg 1d10 (.38 special), Fist/Punch 75%, Dmg 1d3; HP 29*

At least that's close enough for government work, if you are picky and say "but what about if they get poisoned and then..." you need a whole stat block of course.

Comment: +1, yo -- but I think you can get away without the whole stat block, if we're just poisoning thugs.  You might arbitrarily assign a CON score (remember, 10-11 is average!) if it starts to matter, but a full stat block?  I'd save those for the important NPCs.

Comment: Dodge is also an important skill to note for combat and possibly spot hidden.